# Laravel Multiple Files Upload All types of validation with custom message

Tags: laravel

Can any one guide me on custom message validation on multiple files upload using possible validations rules like required, dimensions, ...

See details query.

I have a form with input type file name **pictures** which has the ability to upload multiple files

I have added the below code in the controller on submission

```
public function postPictures(EscortsPicturesRequest $request)
{ 
}
```

Ina FormRequest, I have below code

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class EscortsPicturesRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
          'pictures'   => 'required|min:5|max:10',
          'pictures.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|dimensions:min_width=512,min_height=512',
          'selfie.*'   => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png',
      ];
    }

   
}
```

Now, I want to customize every validation messages like

**min error message**

**max error message**

**dimensions message for each image**

Comment: what have you tried?? what is not working as expected?? show us some code..so is not a code writing service..we are happy to help you to solve any specific problem but you have to come up with something.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon Updated answer. Hoping for your suggestion/Answer to my question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can make follow the below code:
Make a model and mention as below code:

```
public function getPlanRules($act = 'add'){
    return [
        'title'     => "required|string",
        'image.*'       =>  (($act == 'add') ? 'required|' : 
'sometimes|')."image|max:5000",
    ];
}
```

and one thing don't forget to mention below code in form blade

```
'accept'=>'image/*', 'multiple'=>true])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Please check updated question to understand my requirement.